# What is the correct way to specify an object's class with the JSDoc 3 syntax?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

If my code creates a pre-ecmascript 6 style "class", i.e. a constructor function like this:

```
function MyDBPlugin() {
    // ...
}
```

and I am using the [JSDoc3](http://usejsdoc.org/) scheme to document another function that takes an instance of `MyDBPlugin` as an argument, how do I represent the `MyDBPlugin` object?
my first guess was this:

```
/**
 * Some function which takes an instance of MyDBPlugin as an argument
 *
 * @param {Object} plugin An instance of the MyDBPlugin class
 */
function query_database(plugin) {
    // ...
}
```

but `{Object}` seems pretty uninformative, it seems using the classname, `{MyDBPlugin}` would be more descriptive, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Some function which takes an instance of MyDBPlugin as an argument
 *
 * @param {MyDBPlugin} plugin An instance of the MyDBPlugin class
 */
function query_database(plugin) {
    // ...
}
```

how do I represent the `MyDBPlugin` object in the JSDoc syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

If it's a class you can simply use it straight away:

```
/**
* @param {myNamespace.MyClass}
*/
```

If it's a structure, you can create your own `@typedef` http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html and use it, in the same way as above or as you mentioned:

```
/**
* Some function which takes an instance of MyDBPlugin as an argument
*
* @param {MyDBPlugin} plugin An instance of the MyDBPlugin class
*/
function query_database(plugin) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, so because my example is a class, does that mean I can use it straight away, i.e. im not required to create a `@typedef`?

Comment: @the_velour_fog If you only document your class I think it should be fine